# Huawei MediaPad T3 7 can't download my android app from Playstore

Tags: android, google-play, huawei-mobile-services

I have just received a complain from a client that has a Huawei MediaPad T3 7 (Android 6.0). My app is published on Playstore only for tablets, but, this device it is a tablet. Still, my client is getting this message from the Playstore: `Your device isn't compatible with this version in Android`. I have double checked the device's technical characteristics in some webs and everything is good.

What should I do? You guys know what is happening here?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide us your Play Store link?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should always check:

1) If you open your app in the [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) there is a "Device Catalog" link in the side menu. This should tell you if your app should be compatible with this device. What does it say? Can you add this to the question.

2) Device compatibility is most of the time caused by entries in the manifest like sdk version or features. Can you add your manifest to the question?